# Append metadata to transaction from Plutus code

Tags: plutus, metadata

Is there a way to append metadata to transactions that are send from plutus code?

Right now we send transactions from the contracts like follows (or something alike):

```
ledgerTx <- submitTxConstraintsWith @Cube constraints tx
void $ awaitTxConfirmed $ txId ledgerTx
```

I know Alonzo is still in development/testing phase, but I was wondering if there is already something in the API do this or there will be (I cant find anything in the code base as of right now).

Comment: AngelCastillo -  just wondering if you ever got anywhere with this? I'm currently looking into the same requirement.

Comment: Not yet, haven't found any info regarding this. I hope by the time we can access the test net to test our dapps, there is some information.

Comment: Any Updates on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Should one of the answers be marked as accepted?

Comment: None of the answers provided so far are correct

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure in what context you need to append metadata to a transaction, but you may want to check [this documentation](https://alpha.marlowe.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger/html/Ledger-Constraints-TxConstraints.html) for any of these helper functions used for creating `TxContraints`:

- `mustIncludeDatum :: forall i o. Datum -> TxConstraints i o`
- `mustPayToOtherScript :: forall i o. ValidatorHash -> Datum -> Value -> TxConstraints i o`
- `mustPayToTheScript :: forall i o. IsData o => o -> Value -> TxConstraints i o`

The first two require a `Datum` while the last one could be any arbitrary data type converted to a `Data` using `PlutusTx.unstableMakeIsData` or its equivalents.

EDIT:

You might want to look into `StateMachine`s. Especially the transition function (which also requires `TxConstraints`). [You may start with this documentation](https://alpha.marlowe.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-contract/html/Plutus-Contract-StateMachine-OnChain.html),

Comment: Aoaddeola, I am no referring to the data embedded in the UTXO as Datum, I am referring to this: https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2020/11/03/getting-to-grips-with-metadata-on-cardano/

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible right now.

To change that, we would need a hard fork introducing this functionality.

Comment: Why would this require a hard fork?. This is off-chain code, is just a matter of serializing the metadata and appending it to the transaction. Or am I missing something?