# How is metadata typed on the blockchain

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, transaction, ledger, transaction-metadata

I am reading through the haddock documentation to find the way metadata is attached to a transaction. In this documentation [(1)](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger/html/Ledger-Blockchain.html) we have

```
data Blockchain = [Block]
data Block = [OnChainTx]
```

Where

[image: OnChainTx definition]

and

[image: Tx definition]

Now my question is, where and how is metadata appended? My guess is that the only place it could be is in the `txData` field. And if so, take the example of NFT metadata. By CIP 25 it is of a certain JSON format. Is this than converted via JSON -> `data` -> `BuiltinData` and finally wrapped in the `Datum` type?

Comment: I think it just not possible to retrieve metadata from the transaction info that is server into a validator script. Perhaps in the future :)

Comment: Also see https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/2093/append-metadata-to-transaction-from-plutus-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transaction metadata lives outside of the transaction body, inside of the `auxiliary_data`. In the Babbage ledger era, you can see this in the wire spec (CDDL)
[here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/fc4734c93d60158f2db04b416266268d0261c443/eras/babbage/test-suite/cddl-files/babbage.cddl#L17)
In particular, the metadata is defined
[here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/fc4734c93d60158f2db04b416266268d0261c443/eras/babbage/test-suite/cddl-files/babbage.cddl#L329-L337).

In Haskell, you can see that the metadata is
[defined](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/fc4734c93d60158f2db04b416266268d0261c443/eras/alonzo/impl/src/Cardano/Ledger/Alonzo/Data.hs#L241y)
as a map from `Word64` to `Metadatum`.
(I've chosen the Alonzo auxiliary data type to link to here, which is re-used by the Babbage era).

And `Metadatum` is the JSON-like structure defined
[here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-ledger/blob/fc4734c93d60158f2db04b416266268d0261c443/eras/shelley/impl/src/Cardano/Ledger/Shelley/Metadata.hs#L65-L72).

---

**Note** that the transaction metadata is a different type than the `Datum` type used by Plutus, though the structure is nearly identical. (`txData` contains `Datum`, not `Metadatum`.)

---

[CIP-25](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip25/) is provides a schema for expressing NFT Metadata within the transaction metadata. So in particular, it specifies using the number `721` as the transaction metadatum label ( a reference to the Ethereum NFT standard ERC-721 ), and proceeds to specify the rest of the structure. The `cardano-cli` is capable of converting JSON metadata files into the correct wire format, and attaching it to a transaction (with the hash in the transaction body, so that it cannot be corrupted).